# Routing in Angular 7 running in subfolder not working correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular, iis

We are working on migrating our application to a new Angular version. The old one (Angular.JS) was it's own application/repo being served by an .NET Framework 4.5.2 ASP.NET MVC application that would route every call to `Home` which would return a Razor View that contained the angular application and then start it up, possibly routing the suffix of the URL to the actual Angular page. For example, it would route `www.website.com/profile` to the `profile` route in Angular, NOT trying to access a folder called `profile` on the server.
Integrating our API and Angular.JS application is not too too pretty but it worked. The server also has virtual folders in IIS for other subfolders that should be accessed like fonts, images, configs, etc.

Currently I am working on getting the Angular 7 application to run alongside the Angular.JS application. We want to run the Angular 7 application to run inside of a directory of the current application and later on move it to it's own web app because our new Angular application is just a bunch of static files and does not need to be bundled with the server anymore. Basically, there is no need for any ASP.NET MVC configuration.

The current url would be `www.website.com` and return the Angular.JS application. The new one would be `www.website.com/v2/` and would return the Angular 7 application. If we had finished a v2 version of the `profile` page, navigating to `wwww.website.com/v2/profile` should now navigate to the `profile` page of the Angular 7 application.

In IIS, one of the virtual folders is a folder called `dist` which leads to the location of the Angular.JS app files. A new one called `v2` is now configured, which leads to the location of the Angular 7 app files. Another one called `assets` leads to the `assets` folder of the Angular 7 application.

Now, when I navigate to `www.website.com/v2/`, Angular starts and routes me to `www.website.com/v2/home`, which is the home route.

**The issue** is that when I type in `www.website.com/v2/home` myself, it results in the application routing back to `www.website.com`. and thus it boots up the Angular.JS application again. There are no errors or redirects taking place. It seems like it just ignores the part that comes after the `v2/` part even though Angular.JS does this just fine.

**TL;DR** Navigating to `www.website.com/v2` loads up Angular 7, but navigating to `v2/{{Anything}}` results in the application falling back to the Angular.JS application running on `www.website.com`, even though if `{{anything}}` was an internal link in Angular 7, it **would** navigate to the `{{anything}}` route.

I build the Angular project with the following command:

`ng build --configuration=dev --deploy-url=/v2/ --base-href=/v2/`

The routes in the angular 7 application look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canLoad: [NoAuthGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren: './modules/contact/contact.module#ContactModule',
        canLoad: [NoAuthGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'timesheets',
        loadChildren: './modules/timesheet/timesheet.module#TimesheetModule',
        canLoad: [NoAuthGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: './modules/users/users.module#UsersModule',
        canLoad: [NoAuthGuard, NgxPermissionsGuard],
        data: {
          permissions: {
            only: 'seeUsersPage',
            redirectTo: '/403',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: './modules/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule',
        canLoad: [NoAuthGuard],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '403',
    component: Page403Component,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make, for example, typing `www.website.com/v2/contact` in the browser lead to the v2 contact page, while also making the internal navigation possible (so if the user clicks on a "navigate to v2 contact page" inside of the Angular 7 application, it also navigates to the v2 contact page)

Edit: Information about the Angular.JS `Routerconfig` and the back-end `web.config` were requested; I have provided them below.

`RouterConfig`:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/home/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/gebruikers', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/users/users.html',
      controller: 'UsersController',
      controllerAs: 'usersCtrl'
    })
    .when('/profiel', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/profile/profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileController',
      controllerAs: 'profileCtrl'
    })
    .when('/timesheets', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/timesheets/timesheets.html',
      controller: 'TimesheetsController',
      controllerAs: 'timesheetsCtrl',
      reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .when('/facturen', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/invoices/invoices.html',
      controller: 'InvoicesController',
      controllerAs: 'invoicesCtrl',
      reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .when('/opdrachten', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/vacancies/vacancies.html',
      controller: 'VacanciesController',
      controllerAs: 'vacanciesCtrl'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/contact/contact.html',
      controller: 'ContactController',
      controllerAs: 'contactCtrl'
    })
    .when('/help', {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/help/help.html',
      controller: 'HelpController',
      controllerAs: 'helpCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

`Web.Config IIS rewrite rules:`

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect Angular endpoints to MVC Home" enabled="true">
          <match url="^(profiel|timesheets|facturen|opdrachten|contact|help|gebruikers)" negate="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Home" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
     <!-- Some other rules that are not important are here, they redirect HTTP to HTTPS -->
     </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: include your `RouterConfig` here

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Thank you for your comment. I am a back-ender myself, do you mean the Angular.JS `RouterConfig`? If not, what other Routing information about the Angular 7 App do you require? For now I have edited the main post to include the RouterConfig of the Angular JS Application; please take another look if you have time.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?, if yes include the `RouteConfig`

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell you that I was talking about ASP.NET

Comment: Well, it has a default route that you always get, and the default for that route is to go to `Homecontroller`, which returns a View that in combination with the base layout in razor, starts up the Angular JS app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it would always route back to the v1 url is because the angular 7 app contained a `web.config` file that looked like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I believe this is default for an IIS deployment and a team member might have added this. I never thought about having a web.config in a front-end project.

Basically, this rule takes care of rerouting the user to the index.html. For example `www.website.com/folder` would normally bring the user to a folder called `folder` on the webserver, but this is not where Angular runs and could cause a 404. This rule brings the user back to `www.website.com` and then lets angular route the `folder` part.

Because I am running my application in a subfolder, I changed the `url="/"` to `url="/v2/"` and it worked immediatly!

Remember to build the project with `ng build --configuration=dev --deploy-url=/v2/ --base-href=/v2/`! The deploy-url is needed because the scripts/css/other files are not found in the root folder of the server; it is found in /v2/. The base-href is necessary for the router; it should start routing the application at `www.website.com/v2/` and not at `www.website.com/`!

No other iis rewrite rules are necessary, no asp.net config, no special angular routing. Just these simple steps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any modification to your Web.config file? You need to set it up for the base angular app (using the UrlRewrite module) I'd assume it might need a modification for your use case...

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular RoutesV1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/my/app/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

My assumption is you will need to add another 'rule' here. Hope this helps!!! (note: the rewrite is supposed to match your ng build base href value)

Comment: Hello! I have edited my post to show you the IIS rewrite rule values. 

Originally, my virtual folder for Angular 7 was called `distv2` to reflect that `dist` was for Angular JS and `distv2` for Angular 7. Requests that came in for `/v2/` would then be rewritten to `/distv2/`. I had some trouble with thus and thus renamed the virtual folder `v2` so I believe no other rewrites are necessary. 

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your `Web.Config IIS rewrite rules`
2. In your `RouteConfig` change it this way

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // don't change the arrangement, this must be executed first
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "V2",
                url: "v2/{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexV2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
 }
```

Basically what this does is it will catch all your route paths given with the specific route name, the `{*url}` catches all the route segment regardless of the value.

So when we say the url is;

- localhost:4200/test <- this points to `Default`
- localhost:4200/v2/test <- this points to `V2`
- localhost:4200/test/something/2323 <- this points to `Default`
- localhost:4200/v2/test2/test_again/2323 <- this points to `V2`

and in your `HomeController` make sure to add the `IndexV2`

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult IndexV2()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I get where you are going with this, but this would mean that my new Angular application still needs to be integrated with ASP.NET MVC. It would be cooler if they could be decoupled so we can release them seperately if needed. 

Could I not do `localhost:4200/v2/test2/test_again/2323` by using a rewrite rule that would redirect that URL to `localhost:4200/v2` and then let angular do the rest (which is what I want)? Then I'd do almost the same thing as the ASP.NET MVC solution.

Comment: I think its better like this so that you could separate the `_Layout` on each version,

Comment: It is! It is ASP.NET MVC, and the Angular JS is served by using the technique you are describing. But the angular 7 app is just static files so if they are NOT coupled with ASP.NET MVC, we can deploy front-end and back-end seperately. That is why I would prefer a solution where we do not need to do anything ASP.NET MVc specific :)

Comment: hmmm i am not familiar with rewrite rules, this is the only answer i can do for you

Answer (score 0):

**For .Net Core 3 or higher**

---

if 404 happened in the angular subdirectory, it's because of the default route config. so it will be fixed by writing this code on startup.

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) => {
   await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
      !System.IO.Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
      !context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/api/")&&
      !context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/swagger"))
        {
          context.Request.Path = "yousubdirectory/index.html";
          await next();
        }
    });
 
  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```